# Autodesk Forge error 404 from the browser using the tutorial

Tags: autodesk-forge

following https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/
when I try to run the debugger the browser console shows
localhost/:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
This is the second time attempting and I followed the Autodesk instructions closely.

Comment: We will need a lot more information to be able to help you. Which language do you use ? You have any error message in your server console ?

Comment: Perhaps you're simply opening http://localhost/ in your browser? 
You will have to open http://localhost:3000/